# Automatically change what website I pull from

Tags: python, url, count, subprocess

My Python program is pulling from a website from inside of a subprocess. This is working properly.

```
url = 'https://www.website.com/us/{0}/recent/kvc-4020_120/'.format(zipCode)
```

However, the website depending on the zip code, may have multiple pages of results. When this occurs it happens in the format of:

```
https://www.website.com/us/ZIPCODE/recent/kvc-4020_120?sortId=2&offset=48
```

In this case, **?sortId=2&offset=** stays constant. My question is - how I can change the URL automatically, as if I was manually clicking to go to the next page? The only thing that changes would be the offset. It increases by 24 each page. Example:

Page 1, /recent/kvc-4020_120

Page 2, /recent/kvc-4020_120?sortId=2&offset=24

Page 3, /recent/kvc-4020_120?sortId=2&offset=48

etc etc.

This could only reach up to 150 pages. I'm just unsure how to take into account page 1 URL versus anything past page 1.

After pulling from the website, I write to a txt file. I want to automatically check **if there is a next page** and if there is, change the URL and repeat the process. If there's no next page, move on to the next zipcode.

Comment: Can you do `offset=0` for the first page?

Comment: Yes. Just tried it. It works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A `for loop`:

```
for i in ['/recent/kvc-'+str(y)+'_120' 
if x == 0 else '/recent/kvc-'+str(y)+'_120?sortid=2&offset=' + str(x) 
for x in range(0, 48, 24) for y in range(4000,5000)]:
    your_function('web_prefix' + i)
```

Where:

```
range(0, 48, 24)     # increment to 48 by 24 (just an example)
range(4000, 5000)    # Assumed range of Postcodes
```